# pulling data from a previous sheet to populate a value in current sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in a sheet in excel with multiple values and need to pull variables from them and populate in a new sheet.

[image]

K2 has a value of 26.29
K71 has a value of 30.87

I have another column "drawer" stating which drawer those values will go into. the 2 values will go in drawer 1. 
How do I pull that data from this sheet and populate into the new sheet in the correlated location?

[image]

The data sheet in the first picture shows my data and in the second picture, I need to compile it. I planned on using a mark for material 1 and 2 to pull the material code into each column and (if drawer = 1, add k value in B column)

Comment: A screenshot of your data and a screenshot of the expected results would help. Edit your question to do that. Don't put clarification into comments. Post a comment when you have updated your question.

Comment: also read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS`.

Assuming your original data is on `Sheet1`, try:

1. Formula for **TOTAL WEIGHT**: `=SUMIF(Sheet1!N:N,A2,Sheet1!K:K)`.

[image]

2. Formula for **MATERIAL 1**: `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$N:$N,$A2,Sheet1!O:O,"X")`.

[image]

3. Formula for **MATERIAL 2**: `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$N:$N,$A2,Sheet1!P:P,"X")`.

[image]